# jQuery Mobile search input clear with Knockout hasFocus binding

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm having trouble getting the jQuery Mobile search input text "clear text button" to work alongside Knockout's hasFocus binding.

My goal is that when the user is searching, other content on the screen disappears. When the user is not searching, however, that other content is visible. Everything works fine, except...

When I'm typing in the jQuery Mobile search input and click the "X" to clear the input, the search input loses focus, but the input isn't cleared. What *should* happen is the opposite (the search input should be cleared and the search input should keep focus).

[I've created a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4WETR/) to show what I'm talking about.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div data-role="content">
        <h3 data-bind="visible: !IsSearching()">I am some content</h3>
        <input type="search" data-bind="hasFocus: IsSearching" />
        <h3 data-bind="visible: !IsSearching()">I am some more content</h3>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel(), document.getElementById("wrapper"));
});

function MyViewModel() {
    this.IsSearching = ko.observable(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue. I made it so that it only hides other elements on the page if the search text is not focused **and** the search text length is 0.

In case anybody has a similar issue, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b9U8V/) is a link to the working fiddle.

And here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div data-role="content">
        <h3 data-bind="visible: !IsSearching() && SearchText().length == 0">I am some content</h3>
        <input type="search" data-bind="value: SearchText, hasFocus: IsSearching" />
        <h3 data-bind="visible: !IsSearching() && SearchText().length == 0">I am some more content</h3>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel(), document.getElementById("wrapper"));
});

function MyViewModel() {
    this.IsSearching = ko.observable(false);
    this.SearchText = ko.observable("");
}
```